# Making SAS handle very small numbers without rounding

Tags: sas, sas-iml

I have a range of large (4- or 5-digit) numbers, which I need to raise to the -1 power. Because the numbers are all so large, they are obviously going to be very small when raised to that power. When I do it in SAS (using the elementwise operator), all the numbers in the output get rounded(?) to -1. So I get nothing but a lot of minus ones for the output.

Is this indeed the result of rounding? Can I get around this by formatting the output in a certain way? If so, what is the syntax for this? Again, sorry for asking about such simple things, I'm utterly new to SAS.

Code:

```
proc iml; 
  use sasdata.have; 
  read all var {Distance} into D; 
  print D; 
  Dmin = -1##D; 
  print Dmin;
quit;
```

Comment: When you say elementwise operator, do you mean you're in IML?  Or are you just using the language of a matrix language.  Provide example code/data please.

Comment: In particular, I'm a bit confused by your suggestion they be rounded to -1.  They might be rounded to *zero*, depending on how you're displaying them, but I don't see them being rounded to -1.  That implies you have a bigger problem, perhaps incorrect usage of the power operator.

Comment: That's the problem. I **don't** want them rounded to anything. I want them displayed as they are, i.e., all different, albeit raised to the -1 power. Yes, this is in IML.

Comment: It's SAS that, I suspect, does the rounding. The code is as follows:            'proc iml;
use sasdata.have;
read all var {Distance} into D;
print D;
Dmin = -1##D;
print Dmin;       '      now the numbers in Distance, and in D, are all different, but Dmin consists of nothing but -1. I wonder why, and how I can get the real answers in Dmin.

Comment: Also, why is there no (readily apparent) way of doing line breaks here?

Comment: Comments don't have line breaks because they're comments and meant for short pieces..  You need to add that information to your question via edit.

Comment: Just to be clear, [tag:sas-iml] is quite distinct from [tag:sas] and should be tagged as such when you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're raising -1 to the power of 5000 (or whatever), as opposed to the opposite.

```
proc iml; 
  use work.have; 
  read all var {Distance} into D; 
  print D; 
  Dmin = D##-1; 
  print Dmin;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I think I know what's been causing this. The problem was the order of operations! When I changed -1##D to D##-1, the strange transmogrification of all my numbers to -1 stopped, and I finally got the answers of the type I expected. I'm sorry, I'm very stressed and pressed for time at this moment, hence this dumb mistake in my code.